# How to secure access to static resources in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am serving images from a folder outside a web application. I stored images inside C:\source\Pictures. I configured this resource as a static resource in spring's servlet context file:

```
<resources location="file:///C:/source/Pictures/" mapping="/img_resources/**"/>
```

I display images stored in that folder using

```
<img src="<spring:url value='/img_resources/guinnes_choc_cake.jpg/'/>"></img>
```

It work well for me. However, I have security concerns. I would not want to expose a directory in my server to the public.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041839/spring-mvcresources-access-to-outside-folder)

Is there a way to built security around this folder in Spring ?

Comment: Maybe you should accept some answers to previous questions?

Comment: "build security around this folder" - what kind of "security" did you have in mind? What is permitted and what is not?

Comment: @Marcel Some resources online mentioned that by making a folder as a static resource, you are allowing anyone on the net to access that folder. I want to prevent people from doing so.

Comment: I'm asking because your feedback to @ialencar's answer seems odd (to me). You want "security" i.e. access restrictions but on the other hand you don't want that only authenticated users have access? It's either or...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using Spring Security you could add something like this to your Spring context file(s):

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/img_resources/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

Comment: that looks awesome. However does that mean that only users who has been authenticated can view an image ? If that so, then I might end up with a website with no pictures at all. I still would like to let the public view the images.

Comment: Actually isAuthenticated() is one of the expressions available, apparently in your case you would have to use "permitAll". Here you can find all expressions supported by Spring Security: [Expression-Based Access Control](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html).

Comment: Is there a way I can filter per information on user attributes? For example, I have a set of PDF templates organized in a folder structure that depending on user group they shouldn't see files under a certain folder.

Answer (score 1):

There's no particular reason to restrict access to static resources.

Given that the directory structure is well defined and file ordering is semantic (i.e. `img_resources` folder will contain images only), you should permit access to such resources, or even bypass filters altogether to avoid the overhead of passing through the filter chain, e.g.:

```xml
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/img_resources" filters="none" />
```

---

From the [Spring Security tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html):

> We'd prefer not to have static resources processed by Spring
>   Security's filters at all. To achieve this, you can add an additional
>   `<http>` block which only applies to a specific pattern. This must come
>   before the existing block, as it applies to a specific pattern. If no
>   pattern attribute is supplied, the block applies to any request.

Comment: _There's no particular reason to restrict access to static resources_ Not always true. In my case, I have a set of PDF templates that are private and cannot be open to the internet public. One could say I should use document storage for that and have access control, but these resources rarely change and are as static as company logos etc.